# Rcpp: how to monitor the memory usage of variables?

Tags: c++, r, memory, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I have an MCMC algorithm implemented in `Rcpp`. I find that the memory of the program grows larger and larger as more iterations are run and the program will be killed eventually by the Linux system (i.e., "out of memory" error).

I want to monitor the memory usage of each variable to detect the cause of the problem.

I know that in `R`, this can be done using `object.size()`. What is the counterpart in `Rcpp`?

I tried `sizeof()`, which seems to be showing a constant number (e.g., 16). Am I correct that once a variable is declared (e.g., `mat mat1=zeros<mat>(10,10);`), the memory size used by this variable will not change during the run time of the program (e.g., `mat1(0,0)=100000;` will not change the size of `mat1`?)?

If my above understanding is correct, the "out of memory" problem is even more puzzling to me, since I don't alter the size of variables during the program. I identify a computation-intensive function that is called by the main MCMC function during each iteration and is likely the cause for the "out of memory" problem. My question then is why calling the same function will amount to higher and higher memory usage? Is it possible that some memory used by this function is not freed? How should I confirm if this is the case?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: A link to a public repo would help. Does your memory go up if you comment the call to that function? If not, is that function yours?

Comment: Hi @IñakiÚcar, thanks. It is a private project, so I'm not able to share the repo. The function is written by me. The function is used to do a bunch of calculations and returns a single value (of the double type). And, if I comment out the function. the "out of memory" problem is gone. Some input variables to this function are very large, so I use "pass by reference (&)" for these variables, otherwise, the computation time is much much longer. Is it possible that "pass by reference" caused this problem? I haven't tested yet.

Comment: R has decent memory profiling features. See _Writing R Extensions_ and as Rcpp creates R objects, this applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply open the memory management area of your code editor, and add breakpoints on the variable of which you need the value of.
It displays how much bytes of bits each variable is consuming, and also the hexadecimal value.

Comment: Hi Jayansh, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm using Rcpp. The code editor is Rstudio. The cpp file will be compiled first, then called by R script. So, there is no breakpoint option available.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug in my program eventually, although I didn't use the technique of monitoring the memory usage of variables.

It turned out I used "pass by reference" for a variable, then assigned the function result to the variable again. Something like below,

```
struct myStruct{
mat mat1;
double doub1;
}

myStruct RcppFun1(mat & mat1, double & doub1){
//do something to mat1 and doub1
 
myStruct newStruct1;

newStruct1.mat1=mat1;
newStruct1.doub1=doub1;

return newStruct1;
}

//....

myStruct newStruct2=RcppFun1(mat1,doub1);

mat1=newStruct2.mat1;
doub1=newStruct2.doub1;
```

`Struct` was used because I originally wanted to return multiple results from the function. Later, I wanted to reduce the computation time (`mat1` is very large), I used "pass by reference". But, I forgot to remove `Struct` and make the function `void`. The following code works without the problem of "out of memory".

```
void RcppFun1(mat & mat1, double & doub1){
//do something to mat1 and doub1

}

//....

newStruct2=RcppFun1(mat1,doub1);
```

It is also interesting that this bug will result in different errors on different machines:

On one Linux server, it is "out of memory" and gets my program killed.

On another Linux server, it is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".